# VBA operator Not Like

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using a filter on a form currently:

```
Me.Filter = "[duedate] = '" & Me.duedatesearch & "' And [employeename] Is Null"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

This works fine. What I am struggling with is trying to exclude a result from a different field called "workingfor". For example if the above criteria is met AND workingfor is not like "Homer". Not like doesn't seem to be a valid VBA operator. Any ideas?

Thank you.

I have tried the following:

```
Me.Filter = "[duedate] = '" & Me.duedatesearch & "' And [employeename] Is Null" And Not [workingfor] Like "Homer"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Which returns Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: The syntax highlighting should give you the clue.

Comment: If "it works fine" and it's a date field, it is pure luck. If a date field, use: `Me.Filter = "[duedate] = #" & Format(Me.duedatesearch, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#' And [employeename] Is Null"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of issues with your current code:

- As you'll observe from the syntax highlighting when posting your question, the last section of your filter is not part of the initial string, as you have a double-quote after `Null`.
- Unless you were to enclose the `Like` expression within parentheses, the appropriate operator is `Not Like`.

---

For example:

```
Me.Filter = "[duedate] = '" & Me.duedatesearch & "' And [employeename] Is Null And [workingfor] Not Like 'Homer'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

However, since you are not using any wildcard operators within the `Like` pattern, this could alternatively be written using the not equal operator (`<>`):

```
Me.Filter = "[duedate] = '" & Me.duedatesearch & "' And [employeename] Is Null And [workingfor] <> 'Homer'"
Me.FilterOn = True
```

Aside, I find it odd that your field `[duedate]` appears to be a string-valued field, rather than a Date field.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense and thank you for the quick response! Also, yes the data is actually being imported from an email. So the format is kind of a nuisance and not preferable but converting it during import was not something I was familiar with. So I am working with what I have.

Comment: Using text for dates will work when looking for a specific date, but unless the date if formatted in a certain way (not typical date formatting) you cannot search for date ranges. It is easy to convert text to date as long as it is a format supported by Access with `CDate`.

Comment: @didacticone As noted, you can parse dates from text using the [`CDate`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/type-conversion-functions-8ebb0e94-2d43-4975-bb13-87ac8d1a2202) function. I would **strongly** recommend storing such data using a Date/Time field else selection is performed against the text and is dependent on the format of the stored date. Nevertheless, if my answer sufficiently answered your question, please mark it as the solution, so that the question is resolved for others. Refer to [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if you are unsure. Thanks!